# Delphi 6 TRadioGroup with custom TRadioButton controls in it?

Tags: delphi, vcl

I'm using Delphi 6 (actualy BCB6 but nobody uses that, so Delphi advice is fine).  Some controls let you create a custom class of items they can contain, like TListView. Does TRadioGroup have a way to do this without recreating most of the functionality from scratch?  I have my own custom TRadioButton derived controls I created that have a custom look, and I'd like all of my radio buttons to match.

I'm not seeing anything possible looking at the source code in extctrls.pas, and not finding anything online, but figured I'd ask because it is late and I might have overlooked something.

Comment: I use BCB6 in my day job everyday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRadioGroup has no such functionality. What you can do is use a TGroupBox to contain your special controls.